# using GeoIP with django on appengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, geoip

I tried geodjango recently, and worked just fine for me, even without installing that C library.
But when I used the same project in the appengine sdk, it fails whenever it tries to import the GeoIP class
then I looked into the differences, I downloaded the new appengine sdk + django 1.2, and the problem remains!
I tried "python manage.py shell"

`from django.contrib.gis import utils`

`utils.HAS_GEOIP #returns False(django in appengine)`

but when I do the same thing in a native django app the same line returns True
what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GeoIP class is a wrapper around the GeoIP C API. Unfortunately, you can't use C extensions in appengine, so you can't use the GeoIP support that comes with Django.

[`pygeoip`](http://code.google.com/p/pygeoip/) is a GeoIP library implemented in pure Python, you can try to integrate that.

Comment: Yeah I know that, and I already used it, but the feature that I need is not implemented, I mean location related ones like longitude and latitude. I was wondering why they didn't implemented it? or is there any solution, or an alternative for that on the appengine.